# How can I setup a continuous integration (CI) and continuous deployment (CD) for aReactJS app?

Tags: reactjs, continuous-integration, continuous-deployment

I've made a little ReactJS app on my local machine. I did it using Create A React app (https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app). I've also got a unit test for the main app.

I'm supposed to put the project up on a CI/CD platform but I don't know how to do this. I've started the process suing Shippable (http://docs.shippable.com/tutorials/pipelines/samplePipeline/) but the process is not as straigforward as I thought it would be and there are 3 3rd party tools that I had to sign up for.

My question is how can I set up a CI/CD and what is a really easy, free one for beginners with little configuration?

Answer (score 1):

You should use [Circle CI](https://circleci.com/). It is free (if you run only 1 container, i.e. 1 build at a time) and gets your configuration automatically when you add a repository. If you need custom configuration their docs are relatively straightforward. [Travis CI](https://travis-ci.com/) is free forever for open-source projects. It should get your project configuration form connecting to your github repo too.

Comment: Thanks for that! How do I hook Travis up to Circle CL or do I even need to?

Comment: @user1261710 Travis and Circle are 2 separate services. Using only 1 of them is enough.

Comment: Oh, if you want to do continuous deployment then you use Circle Cl with another service? That's what it says on the nav menu in circle.